# Python assigning to a Nested Dictionary in loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to assign values to a nested dictionary but it's giving an unexpected output. Giving an example of the issue with simple variables below.

```
a={1:[None,None],
    2:[None,None]}
b= collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict)

for i in range(0,3):
    if i == 1:
        a[1] = [2,3]
    if i == 2:
        a[1] = [1,1]
    b[i] = a
```

The value of b came out to be:

```
{ 0: {1: [1,1], 2: [None,None]},
  1: {1: [1,1], 2: [None,None]},
  2: {1: [1,1], 2: [None,None]}}
```

Which is not the output that I was expecting. I think this is because I have assigned the variable 'a' as a value to each key and once variable and once the value of 'a' updates, it updates the reference for all keys in the dictionary.

My use case is with slightly different variables where I want a nested dictionary where keys are a list of dates and the values are dictionaries. But, I am not sure how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated. Apologies if the question has been asked before as I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: "once the value of 'a' updates, it updates the reference for all keys in the dictionary"- yes. Thus, you don't want to reference the same dictionary. Instead, you should make changes to a _copy_ of that dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a in the scope of the for loop:

```
import collections

b= collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict)
for i in range(0,3):
    a={1:[None,None], 2:[None,None]}
    if i == 1:
        a[1] = [2,3]
    if i == 2:
        a[1] = [1,1]
    b[i] = a

print(b)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.defaultdict'>,
{0: {1: [None, None], 2: [None, None]},
 1: {1: [2, 3], 2: [None, None]},
 2: {1: [1, 1], 2: [None, None]}})
```

Is this your expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the output I was expecting. Thanks